# windows script creates a clickable Beyond Compare report but now stopped working

Tags: windows, perl, beyondcompare

I have a script that compares two folders in Beyond Compare and generates a clickable html report. This script calls a perl script and Beyond Compare to generate the report. Now after a long time working, it no longer is working. The output of the script says the script cannot find the a file. I have included the Windows shell script, the perl script and the output here. This is all running in IBM Build Forge.

Can someone help me figure out why now the script cannot find the .html file? Also why is the Beyond Compare exit code "1" when before it was "13"?

First the output with the error:

```
start [E:\RBF\EPCOH_Maintenance\EPCOH-20.1.3.0@CHHSSVWR2602]
DEBUG fullpath "E:\RBF\EPCOH_Maintenance\EPCOH-20.1.3.0\prodConfig\config\processes.properties"
DEBUG cwd "E:\RBF\EPCOH_Maintenance\EPCOH-20.1.3.0"
DEBUG base1 "prodConfig"
DEBUG base2 "devConfig"
DEBUG Directory_results_dequoted "diff-PROD-DEV-EPCOH-20.1.3.0"
DEBUG file [config\processes.properties]
DEBUG script ["diff-PROD-DEV-EPCOH-20.1.3.0\config\processes.properties.bc_script"]
+ mkdir "diff-PROD-DEV-EPCOH-20.1.3.0\config\processes.properties.bc_script"
script is "diff-PROD-DEV-EPCOH-20.1.3.0\config\processes.properties.bc_script"

load "ACS Folder Compare2"
criteria rules-based
expand all
file-report &
layout:side-by-side &
 options:display-mismatches,line-numbers &
title:"config\processes.properties" &
output-to:"diff-PROD-DEV-EPCOH-20.1.3.0\config\processes.properties.html" &
output-options:html-color,wrap-word &
"prodConfig\config\processes.properties" "devConfig\config\processes.properties"
Beyond Compare exit code was 1
Could Not Find E:\RBF\EPCOH_Maintenance\EPCOH-20.1.3.0\diff-PROD-DEV-EPCOH-20.1.3.0\config\processes.properties.html
```

Now the Windows script:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(set BC_CLICKABLE_SCRIPT="E:\RBF\internal\bin\make_BC_all_clickable.pl")
(set BC_SESSION="ACS Folder Compare2")

(set cwd=%cd%)
(set Directory_1_dequoted=%Directory_1%)
call :DeQuote Directory_1_dequoted
(set Directory_2_dequoted=%Directory_2%)
call :DeQuote Directory_2_dequoted
(set Directory_results_dequoted=%Directory_results%)
call :DeQuote Directory_results_dequoted
if not defined All_html (set All_html=all.html)
(set All_html_dequoted=%All_html%)
call :DeQuote All_html_dequoted
if not defined Summary_html (set Summary_html=summary.html)
(set Summary_html_dequoted=%Summary_html%)
call :DeQuote Summary_html_dequoted

if not defined Directory_1_dequoted (echo ERROR - Directory_1 must be set& exit /b 1)
if not defined Directory_2_dequoted (echo ERROR - Directory_2 must be set& exit /b 1)
if not defined Directory_results_dequoted (echo ERROR - Directory_results must be set& exit /b 1)

mkdir "%Directory_results_dequoted%"

(set cwd=%cd%)
(set display_option=display-mismatches)
(set del_if_equal=1)
(set base1=%Directory_1_dequoted%)
(set base2=%Directory_2_dequoted%)
for /r %Directory_1% %%g in (*) do set fullpath=%%g&call :compare_a_file
(set base1=%Directory_2_dequoted%)
(set base2=%Directory_1_dequoted%)
for /r %Directory_2% %%g in (*) do set fullpath=%%g&call :compare_a_file
(set del_if_equal=)

(set Summary_temp="summary.tmp")
for /r "%Directory_results_dequoted%" %%g in (*.html) do set fullpath=%%g& call :concat_a_file & del %%g

move %Summary_temp% "%Directory_results_dequoted%\%Summary_html_dequoted%"
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (echo ERROR - move failed& exit /b 1)

dir /b/s "%Directory_results_dequoted%"

(set folder_report_script="%Directory_results_dequoted%\all.bc_script")
(set folder_report_html="%Directory_results_dequoted%\%All_html_dequoted%")
(set folder_report_html_tmp="%Directory_results_dequoted%\%All_html_dequoted%.tmp")

verify >nul:
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (echo ERROR - cannot create %folder_report_script%& exit /b 1)

"%BEYOND_COMPARE%" /silent @%folder_report_script%
if %ERRORLEVEL% geq 100 (echo ERROR - Beyond Compare "%BEYOND_COMPARE%" exited with exit code %ERRORLEVEL%& exit /b 1)

type %folder_report_script%
del %folder_report_script%
%CYGWIN_HOME%\bin\perl.exe %BC_CLICKABLE_SCRIPT% %folder_report_html% > %folder_report_html_tmp%
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (echo ERROR - cannot execute %BC_CLICKABLE_SCRIPT%& exit /b 1)
move /Y %folder_report_html_tmp% %folder_report_html%
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (echo ERROR - cannot move %folder_report_html_tmp% to %folder_report_html%& exit /b 1)

(set cwd=%cd%)
(set display_option=display-all)
(set base1=%Directory_1_dequoted%)
(set base2=%Directory_2_dequoted%)
for /r %Directory_1% %%g in (*) do set fullpath=%%g&call :compare_a_file
(set base1=%Directory_2_dequoted%)
(set base2=%Directory_1_dequoted%)
for /r %Directory_2% %%g in (*) do set fullpath=%%g&call :compare_a_file

exit /b 0

:compare_a_file
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    (call set file=%%fullpath:%cwd%\%base1%\=%%)

    (set script="%Directory_results_dequoted%\%file%.bc_script")

    mkdir %script%
    if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (echo ERROR - cannot mkdir %script%& exit /b 1)
    rmdir %script%
    if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (echo ERROR - cannot rmdir %script%& exit /b 1)
    (set html="%Directory_results_dequoted%\%file%.html")
    if exist %html% goto :end_of_compare_a_file

    (set lhs="%base1%\%file%")
    (set rhs="%base2%\%file%")

    (set nuke_rhs=)
    if exist %rhs% goto :do_not_make_nulled_rhs
        (set nuke_rhs=1)
        (set rhs="%Directory_results_dequoted%\%file%.nulled")
        copy nul: %rhs%
    :do_not_make_nulled_rhs

    verify >nul:

    if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (echo ERROR - cannot write to %script%& exit /b 1)

    type %script%
    "%BEYOND_COMPARE%" /silent @%script%
    (set rc=%ERRORLEVEL%)
    if %rc% geq 100 (echo ERROR - Beyond Compare "%BEYOND_COMPARE%" exited with error exit code %rc%& exit /b 1)

    if not defined del_if_equal goto :skip_del_checks

        "%BEYOND_COMPARE%" /silent /quickcompare /ignoreunimportant %lhs% %rhs%
        (set rc=%ERRORLEVEL%)

        if %rc% geq 100 (echo ERROR - Beyond Compare "%BEYOND_COMPARE%" exited with error exit code %rc%& exit /b 1)
        if %rc% equ  1 del %html%
        if %rc% equ  2 del %html%
        if %rc% equ 12 del %html%
    :skip_del_checks
    del %script%
    if defined nuke_rhs (set nuke_rhs=&del %rhs%)

    goto :end_of_compare_a_file

    :nothing_to_compare
    verify >nul:
    echo ^<^!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"^>>%html%
    if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (echo ERROR - cannot write to %html%& exit /b 1)
    goto :end_of_compare_a_file

    :end_of_compare_a_file
    endlocal
goto :end_of_script

:concat_a_file
    setlocal

    (set concat_file="%fullpath%")

    if exist %Summary_temp% goto not_first_time

        %CYGWIN_HOME%\bin\sed.exe "/<\/body>/d; /<\/html>/d" %concat_file% >%Summary_temp%
        goto :end_of_concat_a_file

    :not_first_time


        %CYGWIN_HOME%\bin\sed.exe "1,/<body>/d; /<\/body>/,$d" %concat_file% >>%Summary_temp%

    :end_of_concat_a_file
    endlocal
goto :end_of_script

:DeQuote
SET _DeQuoteVar=%1
CALL SET _DeQuoteString=%%!_DeQuoteVar!%%
IF [!_DeQuoteString:~0^,1!]==[^"] (
IF [!_DeQuoteString:~-1!]==[^"] (
SET _DeQuoteString=!_DeQuoteString:~1,-1!
) ELSE (GOTO :END_OF_SCRIPT)
) ELSE (GOTO :END_OF_SCRIPT)
SET !_DeQuoteVar!=!_DeQuoteString!
SET _DeQuoteVar=
SET _DeQuoteString=
GOTO :END_OF_SCRIPT

:end_of_script
```

And now the perl script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

my @dir_stack = ();
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    s/\r+$//;
    next unless m!src="BcImages!; # "!;
    next if /<td class="AlignLeft">/;
    my @name = m!align="middle"> ?([^>]+)</td>$!;
    my $name = $name[0];
    # depth: top level is 0.
    my @depth = m!alt="[ \\+|]"!g;
    my $depth = scalar @depth;
    if (0) {
        # Debug.
        print(('____' x $depth), $name, "\n");
        next;
    }
    my $is_dir = 0;
        splice (@dir_stack, $depth);
    if (/alt="<DIR>"/) {

        splice (@dir_stack, $depth, 1, $name);
        $name = '';
        $is_dir = 1;
    }
    my $fullpath = join('/', @dir_stack, $name);
    if (0) {

        print($fullpath, "\n");
    }
    if (! $is_dir) {
        s!align="middle"> ?([^>]+)</td>$!align="middle"><a href="$fullpath.html">$name</a></td>!;
    }
} continue {
    print $_, "\n";
}
exit 0;
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're very unlikely to get an answer to this question as it stands. No-one is going to want to read through all of your Windows script in order to understand what is going on. If you can produce a truncated version that exhibits the same problems, then we may be able to help.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have edited the Windows script to remove the comments and echo statements. Hopefully I will get a response on my issue.